# Does Firefox have a WebSocket message limit?

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

I've been playing around with WebSockets lately, as my lastest game project. I noticed a slight delay of messages and even dropping of messages when I hooked up the keyboard controller to the WebSocket client, which simply sends key presses/releases to the server.

So if I send multiple messages in rapid succession, Firefox seems to pause for some time between each message or even drop them if there are too many.

The same code runs fine in Chrome, with no delay or message dropping. Is this intentional?

**Edit:** Here is a simplified page in which the problem occurs to me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script>
      socket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com/websockettest");
      socket.onopen = function() { message("[[ Connected ]]"); }
      socket.onclose = function() { message("[[ Disconnected ]]"); }
      socket.onmessage = function(e) { message(e.data); }
      function message(msg) {
        document.getElementById("messages").textContent += msg + "\n";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="socket.send('Hey!');"/>
    <input type="button" value="Send two" onclick="socket.send('Hey once!');
                                                   socket.send('Hey twice.');"/>
    <pre id="messages"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that it doesn't matter if I repeatedly punch the "Send" button or just press "Send two".

Comment: What version of firefox? What server? What client side library are you using (if any, if not post some code)? Are you manually enabling websockets support in firefox or are you using web-socket-js?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 4.0.1 with WebSockets enabled and SuperWebSocket as base for the server. Most code is located server-side and being send to the client via the socket. It's a simple update loop called 30 times a second and keychanges are sent during that. I'll see if I can get together a simple test page.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested firefox-4.0.1 with [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) with WebSockets manually enabled and it works without any message loss or delays (in either direction). noVNC sends a lot of traffic in both directions and any messages lost cause a protocol failure which I have never seen with any version of firefox 4 (alpha, beta, 4.0, 4.0.1) and any delays are very obvious because noVNC is highly interactive.

Your client side code looks fine, so my suspicion is that something different about how firefox acts on the wire is triggering a bug in either SuperWebSocket or your SuperWebSocket code. It sounds like you have a fairly simple server that you can reproduce this with. I suggest implementing an equivalent simple test server with a different framework such as [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) (if you have access to a Linux system) or the [Jetty WebSockets servelet](http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/jetty_websocket_server). If it reproduces with one of those then you may have found a bug in firefox's WebSockets client and you should file a bug with Mozilla. If it doesn't reproduce there, then it's probably a bug in SuperWebSocket or in your use of it.

Comment: Could some Firefox config cause this? I haven't changed anything besides enabling WebSockets. I'm just curious why this only this only happens with Firefox and not Chrome. That can't just be an error in the server ..? Well I'm writing my own now, so I wasn't able to test it yet.

Comment: It could be a bug either place although my suspicion is that it is in the server library (or the way you are using it) since the firefox support will have had far more testing (including my own). However, firefox and Chrome won't have the same network timing, fragmentation characteristics, etc so one may trigger a bug in the server while the other does not. This is particularly possible if the developer of SuperWebSocket primarily tested against Chrome and not firefox.